# How can I change Oracle BI Publisher report file name?

Tags: bi-publisher

I am generating reports with Oracle BI Publisher 11.1.1.6. All generated report's file names (excel, word, pdf) are "xdo" (eg. xdo.doc). How can I change report file name to other value? (I mean Report, not Report job).

In simpler words, I click to generate a report, a file xdo.doc is downloaded. I want that file name to be, for example, kitten.doc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my report name contained Lithuanian letters (ą, č, ę, etc.). When I removed them from report name, the files generated by that report where `report name_layout name` as Annjawn said, but not xdo.* like before.

Answer (score 0):

Create the report template as `kitten.doc` and upload it on `Create layout` screen. Use the new template as the template. Now when you click to generate the report it should be named as the template. Hoever, If you schedule the report to run and email itself, you can provide a different name in the `attachment name` field.

Comment: Annjawn, what do you mean by `Create layout screen`? As I understand it's [this screen](http://i.minus.com/iCT5aLc4LGWl4.png). I upload templates by clicking the circled button, my templates have various names but all reports are still generated xdo.*

Answer (score -1):

'Spanish (Chile)' LOCALE,
'PDF' OUTPUT_FORMAT,
 table.description OUTPUT_NAME, ------ here name file output!
'EMAIL' DEL_CHANNEL,